# Can we add more than one value in VueJs "type" attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, oop

I know this is such a ridiculous question, but could we add more than one value in 'type' property? Such as `type="green rounded"` or `type="danger priority"`

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What `type` attribute are you referring to?

Comment: for example, I have my own component named MyModal, and customed like this:
 `<MyModal type="success" class="b-mobile-center b-desktop-center">`

can I input another type after 'success'?

Comment: That would depend on how you're using `type`. If it's configured as a prop of the component then `type="green rounded"` would result in the modal's `type` property having the string value `'green rounded'`. Whether your component understands that depends on how you've written that component. Vue won't have any deeper understanding of it, it just sees the whole string. It's different from `class` in that regard, which Vue does understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a prop with a string type in your component, then use a method to check if the word is included in the string.

For example, prop:

```
props: {
  type: {
    type: String
  }
```

}

Create a function to check if the word is included:

```
propIncludes(segment) {
  return this.type.includes(segment);
}
```

Use the method wherever you want to check:

```
<p v-if="propIncludes('first')">First prop</p>
<p v-if="propIncludes('second')">Second prop</p>
```

And to add your new type to your component, simply go to the parent:

```
<Test type="first second"/>
```

I've added the sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shamir-o0yk9

Comment: @AvocadoFriedEgg Did this answer your original question?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one value for each property. For example `type="green rounded"` is still one value, it's up to you how you want to parse that value.

I created a quick demo that has `type` as a prop and splits it by a space.

```js
Vue.component("MyModal", {
  template: "<div>{{type ? type.split(' ').join(', ') : 'No Type'}}</div>",
  props: ["type"]
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <My-Modal type="danger red"></My-Modal>
</div>
```